# zbar in android studio 785 could not load needed library 'libiconv.so' for 'libzbarjni.so'

Tags: android, opencv, zbar

I am trying to import both opencv and zbar and work with both in the same project i imported opencv noramlly and it worked i copied the .so files to the jniLibs and then i opened the camera and it worked fine then i imported zbar by copying the .jar file in libs and .so files from each folder to the same folder that had opencv .so files for example i copied the 2 zbar .so files from x86 to jniLibs x86 with other .so of opencv this is the error i got

```
10-25 18:54:09.336    1447-1447/com.example.amgad.medikar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.example.amgad.medikar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:   785 could not load needed library 'libiconv.so' for 'libzbarjni.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libiconv.so' not found)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
        at net.sourceforge.zbar.ImageScanner.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

```
at com.example.amgad.medikar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
```

that line is

```
 scanner = new ImageScanner();
```

so i tried to load the libraries manually

```
 static{
    System.loadLibrary("libiconv");
    System.loadLibrary("libzbarjni");
}
```

then i got this error

```
10-25 19:15:33.295    1495-1495/com.example.amgad.medikar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libiconv: findLibrary returned null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary( "iconv" );
}
```

For more information, look at the package Samples in the ZBarAndroidSDK-0.2.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had other .so library too in my project.

What I did is:

1. put each .so file under correct cpu type (as you already did)
2. put all cpu folders inside another folder called "lib"
3. zip lib folder and rename it to lib.jar
4. place lib.jar inside your app libs folder
5. add `System.loadLibrary( "iconv" );` as suggested above
6. add this line to the build

   ```
   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') }
   ```

Hope this helps